# Error "TypeError: mercadopago.configure is not a function"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, mercadopago

Estoy realizando la integracion de checkoutpro de mercadopago con node. Uso linuxmint. EL error que me muestra al ejecutar "npm start" es el siguiente:

facundo@facundo:~/Repositorios/Donaciones_MercadoPago/server$ npm start

> server@1.0.0 start
> nodemon server.js

[nodemon] 3.0.1
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,cjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
/home/facundo/Repositorios/Donaciones_MercadoPago/server/server.js:7
mercadopago.configure({
^

TypeError: mercadopago.configure is not a function
at Object. (/home/facundo/Repositorios/Donaciones_MercadoPago/server/server.js:7:13)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:86:12)
at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.18.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Este error solo desaparece cuando comento las siguientes lineas de codigo:

mercadopago.configure({
access_token: "aqui el acces token",
});

Comment: Verifica la versión del módulo de MercadoPago que estás utilizando. Puedes hacerlo con el siguiente comando:
npm list mercadopago

Si la versión es antigua, podrías intentar actualizarla con:

npm update mercadopago

Si nada de lo anterior funciona, podrías intentar eliminar el módulo y reinstalarlo:
npm uninstall mercadopago
npm install mercadopago

Comment: Antes que nada muchas gracias por la ayuda. La version que tengo instalada  es la ultima  mercadopago@2.0.1. Probe desinstalar y volver a instalar y es el mismo error. Tambien prove con proyectos desde cero y lo mismo. Se podra instalar una version anterior?

Comment: No creo que funcione con version anterior. No se me ocurre nada mas que cambiar el entorno. Actualiza linuxmint o cambia a otro entorno diferente...

Comment: Probaré. Muchas gracias por la ayuda !

Comment: ¿De qué forma estás importando la librería?

Comment: @DanielRodríguezMeza Hola. No recuerdo bien pero lo solucioné instalando una version anterior de mercadopago

Answer (score 0):

Tengo el mismo problema, y al parecer es un conflicto por las versiones.
En la mayoria de los tutoriales trabajan con versiones anteriores a la 2.0, en donde se puede acceder a "mp.configure".
Si trabajas con versiones mayores a la 2.0 y mostras por consola a mp, fijate que te muestra este objeto:

```
{
  MercadoPagoConfig: [Getter],
  CardToken: [Getter],
  CustomerCard: [Getter],
  Customer: [Getter],
  Invoice: [Getter],
  IdentificationType: [Getter],
  PaymentRefund: [Getter],
  PaymentMethod: [Getter],
  Payment: [Getter],
  PreApproval: [Getter],
  PreApprovalPlan: [Getter],
  Point: [Getter],
  Preference: [Getter],
  OAuth: [Getter],
  MerchantOrder: [Getter],
  User: [Getter],
  default: [class MercadoPagoConfig]
}
```

entonces no es posible acceder directamente a "configure" ya que no existe.
Podrias acceder a la documentacion oficial para realizar la configuracion con versiones superiores.